# BeautifulSoup prettify output into html

Tags: html, flask, beautifulsoup, jinja2

I am trying to make output like below.
[image]

But I got this instead.
[image]

Below is my flask code:

```
@app.route('/finance')
def finance():
    page = requests.get("http://dataquestio.github.io/web-scraping-pages/simple.html")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    soup = soup.prettify()
    return render_template('finance.html', page=page, soup=soup)
```

HTML code:

```
{{ soup }}
```

How can I achieve the neat format in the first image?

Comment: How does the rendered markup look like? Have you tried wrapping soup's output into `<pre>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user [Nico Haase](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1116230/nico-haase) mention, you should wrap your code in `pre` tag. I tried it locally, it works.

```
<pre>
{{ soup }}
</pre>
```